# How to create password protected RSS feed in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Creating RSS feed in rails is easy. I need a simple way to password protect the RSS feed. I am thinking http basic authentication.

I googled but could not find any article about creating password protected RSS.

Answer (score 4):

I have this in my ApplicationController

```
def xml_authorize
  if request.format == Mime::XML
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == 'foo' && password == 'bar'
    end
  end
end
```

Then I just apply a `before_filter :xml_authorize` to the actions that I want to password protect for XML requests only, but still want to serve normally with html.

---

[Here](http://www.whatcodecraves.com/articles/2008/11/25/how_to_make_an_api_for_a_rails_app/)'s where I got the inspiration from.

Answer (score 2):

Just use whatever auth system you use on your regular controllers. If the user is logged, and session is alive he will be able to download the feed.

Answer (score 1):

How is HTTP authentication any different on RSS feeds than other controller actions? (This is not necessarily a rhetorical question - is it actually different?)

Have you tried [just using the Rails HTTP Basic Authentication methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Feeds are meant to be fetched in regular intervals without user interaction. 
RSS-Feeds can be consumed by something different than a browser. For example, 
I have a phone where I can create a widget for the start screen from a rss-feed-link. Great function. Unfortunately authentication does not work for this widget.
And there is no user interface to put in username and password. So the authentication need to be part of the url, with all the bad security implications...

On the other hand you don't need a session to answer a feed-request.

So the solution is a create a special key for the user, and store it in the user table.
Then use it when you display the link to the rss-feed. In the feed-method, you use this key to retrieve the user, but you don't create a session. This way, even when a hacker somehow got a valid key, the hacker can only view the rss-feed, but not access the rest of your application.

If you already use some library for authentication, there may already some solution implemented for this. In Authlogic, is is the class SingleAccessToken, and you need to add a column 'single_access_token' of type string to your user table. Then authlogic creates some cryptic key when are saving the user record. You than add this key as the GET-Parameter 'user_credentials' to the url of the private rss-feed

Answer (score 0):

Like knoopx said, If you use an authentication system like [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) you should be able to specify the authentication type in the controller. You can then specify http basic authenication. Then you can, if you choose, include the authentication in the URL for the RSS Feed.

e.g:

```
http://username:password@example.com/rss
```

<strike>(sorry to break the URI up like that, but I don't have enough reputation points to post multiple links :( )</strike>

Comment: ...However, the password should never be stored in plaintext in your database anyway, and making so that if someone clicks a link their password is shown to absolutely anyone who might be with them is just unsafe.

Comment: Matchu, I agree that the password should never be stored in plain text in the password. I was just putting it in there as an example of what can be achieved. Obviously, the best scenario is that the RSS client has the authentication mechanism built in.